# Convolution, Image on image

Tags: cntk

I will like to make a Convolution on an image with another image.

```
model (fromImage,toImage) = {   
    fromImageCon= Convolution(toImage ,
                              fromImage, 
                              (64:64:1),
                              stride=1,
                              autoPadding=(true:true:true),
                              mapDims=1
                              )     
    z = LinearLayer {labelDim} (fromImageCon)
    }.z
```

I am getting the error :"**EXCEPTION occurred: Node 'ol.toImageCon.res.x' (Plus operation): Minibatch data cannot be interpreted as a single 2D tensor.**"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Source/CNTK/BrainScript/CNTKCoreLib/CNTK.core.bs#L621), the first parameter to the `Convolution` primitive is a learn-able weight. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In image analysis, it is common to convolute and image with another image. I am trying to make an network that can find an small image in an larger image like http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Pedestrian_Detection_in_CSharp
To make it simple I have removed all other layers except the convolution layer.

Comment: Note that inputs to models have a batch axis, i.e. you should consider the code above trying to run convolution on a batch of images with a specific kernel image. If that's what you want, you can initialize the toImage as constant with the small image.